# how to add offline or online payment method for customer group in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, customer-group

I have add offline or online payment method for customer group  add to admin in back-end 
EX:
Offline : Check/money order
Online  : Paypal

Comment: I recommend for this link : https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter

Comment: Ok I will try this